# Design form with multiple color in pdfbox with text

Tags: pdf, text, pdfbox

I want to design form like this in pdfbox. I am not sure, how I can make that?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? A quick Google search reveals numerous articles on creating tables with pdfbox, among them some add on libraries for pdfbox for creating tables.

Comment: @user1213199 ... including one library that you have used in your other question.

Comment: problem is i cant find this method as                                                                                        table.getLayouters().add(new DefaultCellLayouter(Styles.DEFAULT));